# Different CSS style for each paragraph within the same DIV

Tags: css

Currently I have the following piece of code available which needs to be styled:

```
<div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">     
    <p>summary</p>
    <p>body</p>
</div>
```

I would like to keep the HTML as-is and style the 'p' of both the summary and the body in a different way.

Is that possible? How? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep it is :

```css
div p:nth-child(1){
  color: red;
}

div p:nth-child(2){
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">     
    <p>summary</p>
    <p>body</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :nth-child() cssSelector to apply different styles for each tag. Look at below example.

```
div p:nth-child(1){
   color:red;
 }

div p:nth-child(2){
   color:green;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do that:

```
<p style="background-color:#000000;"></p>
```

Or do that:
First, add the "id" tag in your paragraphs tags.

```
<p id="bodyParagraph"></p>
```

Second, on the head tags include the:

```
<style>
    #bodyParagraph{
        background-color:#000000;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you want to add specific classes to the summary paragraph and another for the body paragraph? Nothing wrong with that.
`<p class="summary">` and `<p class="body">` with their respective styling.

If you *really* want to avoid using a specific class for each, I'd suggest checking out the :first-child and nth-child pseudo-elements, so you style the first paragraph of that particular div one way and any other paragraphs a different way.

Assuming that the body paragraph might be multiple paragraphs, I'd strongly recommend against this approach since it will be hacky, more confusing, and more time consuming than just giving each paragraph its own style.

**Sources:**

[W3Schools - first-child pseudo-element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) and [W3Schools - nth-child pseudo-element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)